# Why did Li Luo's hair turn white?

Tags: ice-fantasy

When "Li Luo" put on Ka Suo's ring, her hair turned white, like that of an immortal of the Ice Clan (also, um, her name changes to Li Jing? Maybe?). Her eyes, though, stay dark brown, and do not change to the blue more characteristic of the Ice Clan. It didn't seem to come as a surprise to anyone, either. Neither "Li Luo" nor Ka Suo panicked. However, it didn't seem to have been mentioned beforehand.

Why was this? Clearly, marrying into the Ice Clan does not change the hair color of an immortal (for instance, Lian Ji).  It seems like it must have been a property of  the ring.

But what's going on? Did Ka Suo somehow give "Li Luo" some portion of his spiritual power? Did he make her immortal, even (despite her eye color staying the same)? Was it just a cosmetic change, and if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Because Ka Suo put his soul into the ring

In *Ice Fantasy Destiny*, we see a flashback to the days of *Ice Fantasy*, in which Ka Suo gives Li Luo a ring.

> KA SUO: I know how I can make you live 270 years with me. Li Luo, I made this ring long ago, but I was never able to give it to you. Now, I sealed a part of my soul in  there. When you wear it in the future, you will feel immense power.

As such, he could share part of his lifespan with Li Luo, at the expense of shortening his own.